# Oscillating For Loop Through Recursive Action

Tags: c++, oop, recursion

My problem here is that my base case is never executing because the loop, which is the main component for running the application is not executing. I was thinking of making an embedded for loop, though, I could not think of a way to make the for loop oscillate from the max vector position to the minimum vector position. Also, a small thing to note before viewing is v3 contains both objects A and B because object C is a superclass of A and B.

MCVE version: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6fdc017118e98f2

```
    void Obj::objhelper()
    {

        recurisivehelper();


        if ((v1[0].getx() == 0 && v2[0].getx() > 0) ||
            (v1[0].getx() > 0 && v2[0].getx() == 0))
        {
            if (v1[0].getx() == 0 && v2[0].getx() > 0)
            {
                print(3);
                return;
            }else
            {
                print(4);
                return;
            }
        }

        else if(v1[0].getx() > 0 && v2[0].getx() > 0)
        {
            objhelper();
        }

        return;
    }

//This method is not touched
//This is a recursive helper method of the helper method of the main method
    void Obj::recursivehelper()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            if (v3[i].gety() == "str1" ||
                v3[i].gety() == "str2" ||
                v3[i].gety() == "str3")
            {
                int temp = 0;

                Obj1 obj(v1,:v2);
                obj.display();

                v3[i].doa(v3[i + 1]);

                obj.display();
                v2[0]--;
            }else if (v3[i].gety() == "str4" ||
                      v3[i].gety() == "str5"   ||
                      v3[i].gety() == "str6"  )
            {

                Obj1 obj(v1,sv2);
                obj.display();

               v3[i].doa(v3[i + 1]);


                obj.display();
                v1[0]--;
            }
        }

        return;
    }
```

Comment: If you posted an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e.g. in http://ideone.com/ or http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ with a run-able main, this problem would be very attractive to solve.

Comment: Here is an MCVE version of it in C++ http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a268bd6b5618a768

Comment: Nice, it is far better.   However, it is not compilable, so it is still not MCVE except that this question is asking about compiler-error.   ... I guess someone are staring at this question, and you will get an immediate answer as soon as you provide MCVE.

Comment: I actually fixed a couple of issues, so here is the better one http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21ad26f53ff5e3a7. I'm not sure if it's actually running or just sitting idol though.

Comment: To check, you can see the grey console below.  Look for "error".  There are still a few of them.  To reduce some error in this demo, I recommend a dirty trick "using namespace std;".

Comment: Thanks, I think I may have [recreated the error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6e90c6506df34f0) as it sent me to the vector class, and that is what happens when I run my actual code.

Comment: Do you forget `>` in `void recursivehelper(std::vector<int&,`?  After adding, it would still cause error.   Is the new error still match the actual code's error?

Comment: Thanks for that I press & instead of > Here's the infinite recursion http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6fdc017118e98f2

Comment: Great job, I will try to review it now.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a parameter [by value](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/72-passing-arguments-by-value/) is different from [passing by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/).

Here is the problematic part :-

```
void recursivehelper(std::vector<int>v1, std::vector<int>v2, std::vector<std::string>v3) {
    ....
        v1[0]--;   //<-- modify internal copy
        v2[0]--;
    ...
    return;
}
```

The line `v1[0]--;v2[0]--;` modifies **copy** of `v1` and `v2`, and actually does nothing that effect `v1` or `v2` from the caller (`recursivefunc()`) perspective.

One of the easy ways to make it works as expected is to pass by reference.

Change the signature of both declaration and implementation from

```
void recursivefunc(std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::string>);
void recursivehelper(std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::string>);
```

to

```
void recursivefunc(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>&, std::vector<std::string>&);
void recursivehelper(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>&, std::vector<std::string>&);
```

Here is the [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6c080b756bfc56f).